# I can't build ios in flutter with google sign in package

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

I can't build ios with google sign in package in flutter.
How can I do for this?
Best Regards

[image]

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           10.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/joeandrei/Documents/lastMyhaircut/myhaircut/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:19:
    /Users/joeandrei/Documents/lastMyhaircut/myhaircut/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.h:38:1: error: expected ','
    API_UNAVAILABLE(macCatalyst)
    ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/joeandrei/Documents/lastMyhaircut/myhaircut/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.h:19:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.4.sdk/usr/include/os/availability.h:93:171: note: expanded from macro 'API_UNAVAILABLE'
        #define API_UNAVAILABLE(...) __API_UNAVAILABLE_GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__,__API_UNAVAILABLE6, __API_UNAVAILABLE5, __API_UNAVAILABLE4,__API_UNAVAILABLE3,__API_UNAVAILABLE2,__API_UNAVAILABLE1, 0)(__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                                                                                                                              ^
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone X.
```

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: i am using google_sign_in 4.0.14

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `google_sign_in: 4.0.6` without the '^' and run flutter clean and build again

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and did open an issue on github: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1772